# how to use jquery hash without hash tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have  index.php and cpanel page that i load it by jquery into index body

```js
if (location.hash == '#cp') {
  $(".body").load('cpanel/index.php');
};
```

i don't want to use long path folders i just need to set hash but,

i want to use hash without hashtag(#)

```
example.com/#cp
```

i want it like `facebook.com/username`

```
example.com/cp
```

without any folders path .

Answer (score 0):

You can use server-side route methods to handle the URLs. In case you want to use JS only you can manipulate location properties like `location.pathname` to manipulate URLs.